# how to validate property grid in ext js 2.3

Tags: extjs

i want to do it explicitly in ext js 2.3. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.grid.PropertyGrid i have included this

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.PropertyGrid({
                    title: 'Properties Grid',
                    autoHeight: true,
                    width: 500,
                    //renderTo: 'grid-ct',
                    source: {
                        //"(name)": "My Object",
                        //"Created": new Date(Date.parse('10/15/2006')),
                        timeofday: "12:00 PM",
                        "Available": false,
                        myVersion: 1,
                        //"Description": "A test object"
                    },
                    customEditors: {
                        timeofday: new Ext.form.TimeField({
                            selectOnFocus : true,
                        }),
                        myVersion: {
                            xtype: "textfield",
                            allowBlank: true,
                        }
                    },
                    propertyNames: {
                        timeofday: 'Time of Day',
                        myVersion: "Version",
                    },
```

In customeditor method

```
customEditors: {timeofday: new Ext.form.TimeField({
    selectOnFocus : true})
```

This should edit the time field but it generates new timefield on next line. I want validation in this way http://jsfiddle.net/existdissolve/wMcQk/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may write Timefield in the same manner as myVersion:

```
timeofday: {
    xtype: "timefield",
    selectOnFocus: true
    }
```

Comment: ya when i enter any text it is taking the last time value. I want to show it as an error in red box with the same text that i have entered  in it .